# What's the meaning of making a method static? -For dummies

Tags: c#, static, instantiation

I have a method that takes a string argument (a file path), and i wanna make it acessible to all forms.

I know that when i use

```
public static methodname(string path) { //code }
```

it will work on all forms as long as i call it, and when i dont have static there i have to instantiate it.. the thing is.. why this difference? What does it really means to instantiate? I've read a few topics about it, but i couldn't quite understand how, can you take the time to explain it to a amateur beginner?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading a good book or tutorial.

Comment: Please reefer the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: Read [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods). It is same in Java.

Comment: Going strictly by the title: here is [C# for Dummies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/For-Dummies-Stephen-R-Davis/dp/0764508148)

Comment: The problem is that all of the sources i've found show a meaningful language, so for a beginner it's not easily understood. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's also strange that a few users flag my question, and tell me to go read some books, while others answer in a simple and clear language accessible to professionals of other areas, which i believe is the constructive thing to do. It's not the first time i find some keyboard warriors when i try to clarify some basic elements. Please forgive me, for I might have sinned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use non-static classes or object oriented classes, if you want to maintain a state.

When you use static classes, there isn't any state.

For example:

```
class HelloWorld
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public void SayHello()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Name + " hello!");
    }
    public void SayHi()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Name + " hi!");
    }
}
```

You would use the above like this:

```
HellowWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
obj.Name = "John";
obj.SayHi(); 
obj.SayHello();
```

If that was a static class:

```
static class HelloWorld
{
    public static void SayHello(string Name)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Name + " hello!");
    }
    public static void SayHi(string Name)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Name + " hi!");
    }
}
```

You would call the above like this:

```
HelloWorld.SayHello("John");
HelloWorld.SayHi("John");
```

As you can see, you are repeating yourself.

So it all depends on how you want the class to behave. If you want *do and forget*, then static class is your friend. If you don't want it to *forget* something, then use Objects

Comment: It's a very neat answer, there's only a thing i don't understand, what is the advantage in using a non-static class? What kind of behaviour could i change using it? It seems more complex so i'm guessing it has more potential.Because in those examples there's no limitation on using static or non-static @Amit Joki

Comment: Also, why can't i use a static method to make a combobox or a textbox public? what do these items have, that make them non-static?

Answer (score 3):

This tells the compiler that he method is entirely self-contained, and does not rely on or utilize any *object state*, or *instance-based* properties or fields of the class it is defined in.  As a consequence, you do not need to instantiate an instance of the type (class or struct) in order to use this method.  It becomes like a global function or subroutine which you can call simply by name, (you must use the class/struct name and method name) without any preparation.

to call non-static method `MyMethod()`  on class `foo`

```
var f = new foo();
f.MyMethod();
```

to call static method `MyMethod()` on class `foo`

```
foo.MyMethod();
```

You can define static methods in a non-static class, (if the method does not rely on any object state doesn't mean the object does not have any state...).   but you cannot put non-static methods in a static class (if the method requires access to object state, then it obviously can't be in a class that has no state).

Now you can write a method that does not require object state, and neglect to declare it as static.  Then it would require the same usage syntax like a non-static method even though it is functionally static. That is an error the compiler will accept (although many tools like Resharper will warn you about this).

Answer (score 1):

This is classic programming. Static methods are used when all the data you need is from the parameter. Also static methods are called upon a class. When you make a method static then it uses instance variables to do something. Instantiontain allows a user to initialize all fields in that class then the user can call a method upon that object that behind the scenes uses instance variables to do something.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, a non-static method means that it belows to an object (so you have to instantiate one in order to use the method. On the other hand, a static method below to the class, so when you call it, it has nothing to do with an object.

For example:

```
class C{
    static int f(int i){return i+1;}
}

C.f(2); // returns 3
```

You only can do it if the method is static, it is, it belongs to a class, not an object. If f() were not be static, you have to instantiate one object to use it:

```
class C{
    int f(int i){return i+1;}
}

C.f(2); // invalid!
C c = new c(); c.f(2); // returns 3
```

On the other hand, this code is invalid:

```
class C{
    int a;
    static int f(){return a;}
}
```

C.f(); // Invalid: each instance of C has it own attribute a.